# Hyperledger fabric create the new block when we use storage

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using hyper-ledger fabric with 2 organisation and peers with the chain-code installed in all the peers. I am using the storage to keep the state of blockchain on local drive.

If i am using the storage current blockchain state, when i stop all container of peers, orderer and run again, it adds the one extra block without doing the transaction, all the time when i stop and start all the container. How this block is getting created and what is the purpose of this extra block?

Comment: will you paste the raw block, I guess configuration details

Comment: What do you mean it added one extra block?  To the peers?  What command(s) are you using to stop/start?